# arithmetic symbols and operators are wrongly diplayed

Tags: html

I entered data into table in phpmyadmin database. some data are (3/4, 1", Celsius degree symbol) 
for example:
in excel: 
          Elbow 90° ½" Galvanized threaded female
after import to phpmyadmin and HTML:
          Elbow 90ø «" Galvanized threaded female

in excel: 
           Water hose  ¾"

in Phpmyadmin and HTML:
            Water hose ?'

Please, help me to solve

Comment: You're using the wrong encoding.  You should use UTF8 everywhere.

Comment: I'm using  (utf8_general_ci) for all tables

Comment: You also need to use UTF8 in your source and your HTTP headers.

Comment: and (utf8_bin) for database

Comment: How to use UTF8 in source and HTTP header?  LIKE THIS (<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)